# Swift Core Data displayed in OS X Tableview

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, nstableview

I am new to xCode and Swift. I used to develop software using Visual Studio - Visual Basic.

I am browsing through tutorials and tutorials and tutorials but nowhere can I find an example of how to display a Core Data Entity created in Swift in a NStableview MAC OS X Application. All the tutorials are for iOS application.

I have created the savings methods but all I need to do is to display my saved records in a tableview. HOW CAN I DO THAT?
Are there anybody out there that can give me advice on this.

Comment: Do you understand Obj-C ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Preparation

First of all, your ViewController must inherit from `NSTableViewDelegate` and `NSTableViewDataSource`:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource
```

Then, like in iOS you must implement the delegate methods for the `NSTableView`.

Make an `IBOutlet`, something like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
```

## Delegate and DataSource

Then in the viewDidLoad(), set the delegate and the dataSource to self:

```
tableView.setDelegate(self)
tableView.setDataSource(self)
```

**And implement the required methods:**

**For the number of rows:**

```
func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return yourData.count //your data ist the array of data for each row
}
```

**For the row data:**

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject? {

    if tableColumn!.title == "firstColumnTitle" //if you have more columns
    {
        return yourData[row].first
    }
    else //second column
    {
        return return yourData[row].second
    }

}
```

**For selection: (optional)**

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    var row = tableView.selectedRow
    // a row was selected, to something with that information!
}
```

If you have any questions, don't hesitate!

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. I will have a look at this. This is a complete different world of coding from what I am used to.

Comment: No hard feelings. We have all been there.